# Download photo with http authentication - MWPhotobrowser on ios

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, mwphotobrowser

I'm trying to figure out how to download images in the MWPhotoBrowser when the image URLs require authentication.  In my case the images are on S3 and I need to pass a key along with the url.   I don't see a way to handle this in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my approach and instead get a tokenized URL from S3 and then pass clean urls into the photo browser.